# Meta question 1154: "Too many redirects"

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

When I attempt to go to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154) I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS from Chrome, whether I'm logged in or not (the latter using an incognito window).

IE 8 seems to just infinite loop: eventually SE itself complains "Too Many Requests - Stack Exchange" and blocks my IP address temporarily!

Comment: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Maybe that's the question about the set of all questions that don't link to themselves.

Comment: @Gerry It's clopen (both open and closed), not something that CS folks normally encounter; hence the infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Is the closed indicator in the title preventing access to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112091/is-the-closed-indicator-in-the-title-preventing-access-to-a-question); same issue that happened here.

I edited the question to stop this.